# magento catalog product image is showing quantity

Tags: php, magento, catalog

Am working on magento 1.9.2 and faced a problem with the images in home page and sometime in catalog page.

Image size automatically changes and showing [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZNbi.png) as in background need to remove that because of this image size enlarge and causing problem with interface.

[image]

Comment: is 1 is qty ? if possible try to find solution or in worst case, you can hide it through css

Comment: yes 1 is qty, to find out the solution i posted here

Comment: i guess in  listing page, qty related code is displaying, did you try to hide through css ?